# Google sign in doesn't respond

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two login option, normal login and google sign-in.Normal login work fine,but google sign-in is not.

I click the google sign-in button and i can see the accounts.So i click the account but nothing happen.Also i can't see the user data on firebase.

I don't get any error on emulator or android studio.I miss something but what ?

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImM2sTvs1H0) for google sign-in method.

**UPDATE ERROR LOG**

I found error log finally.Problem is i had building signed(release) apk every time, but i added debug SHA1 code on firebase.Just i run debug mode on emulator.

```
    EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.app.surebettips, PID: 3806
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.app.surebettips/com.app.surebettips.Login}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken.
            at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
            at 

/****HERE***/
com.app.surebettips.Login.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(Login.java:467)
            at com.app.surebettips.Login.onActivityResult(Login.java:376)

/****HERE***/
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    09-06 09:49:09.566 3806-3806/com.app.surebettips I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3806 SIG: 9
```

Line : 467

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
```

Line: 376

```
firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). It'll make your life very simple and code very much shorter.

Comment: Thank you for advice.I still trying save my time.

Comment: @Op.Kemal Do you have any google sign-in errors? Are you sure you have enabled google sign-in method in your Firebase Console? Please responde with @.

Comment: Good for you bro. It's some of the good stuff. Once you use it, never again will you use the conventional methods again.

Comment: I do.Google document gives: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
And I do this way.Then i tried implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1' doesn't work both.

Answer (score 0):

An empty response from Google Sign In is usually due to an incorrect SHA fingerprint or if it's not defined at all in the Google API Console. In the video, the author uses an old tutorial.
Here is the current version: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin
and it contains a link to the standard Google Sing in integration tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

This is necessary because in this tutorial there is another link to Configure a Google API Console:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
where you need to configure your current API project, usually it has name as Google Play Android Developer or some others, if you changed it or created some other project in API console.

You need to setup your SHA-1 fingerprint and package name here. If you set it to the right project (if you have more than one) Google sign in will work correctly.

Also you are using GoogleSignIn Client, so you have to use it also when you are create Sing In Intent

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

So please check this tutorial from Google and implement it as documentation says and everything will work fine.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 0):

Inside onActivityResult callback do the following:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        try {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // User is logged in on google platform
            Log.v(TAG, "Account token:" + account.getIdToken()); //NON-NLS
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e); //NON-NLS

            String messageToDisplay = "Authentication failed.";
            switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.API_NOT_CONNECTED: //17
                    messageToDisplay += "The client attempted to clearPreferences a method from an API that failed to connect.";
                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.DEVELOPER_ERROR: //10
                    messageToDisplay += "The application is misconfigured.";
                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.ERROR: //13
                    messageToDisplay += "The operation failed with no more detailed information.";
                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR: //8
                    messageToDisplay += "An internal error occurred.";
                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.INVALID_ACCOUNT: //8
                    messageToDisplay += "Invalid account name specified.";
                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED: //8
                    messageToDisplay += "Please Sign In to continue.";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to understand why your sign-in is not working

Comment: I found error log finally.Problem is i had building signed(release) apk every time, but i added debug SHA1 code on firebase.I don't use your code.Just i run debug mode on emulator.Update my first message.

Answer (score 0):

**After complete Code side must do other things from Google and Firebase Console.**

1. Create SHA-1 Key from your pc.

   - from Right side of Android studio find Gradle option -> app  -> Signing Report. You will get SHA-1 key in log area when it done. (Watch in pic.)

[image]

- add this key in Google firebase Console in App module

[image]

- after this module, download ***'google-services.json'*** and paste it into project -> app -> :here paste that file: ex:/ D:\Thor_PC\Androidroject\android-customer_new\app

  [image]
- and at the last option must check **Google Service is Enable or not** in Console.
- Go to firebase console -> Engage (left side)  -> Authentication -> Sign-in Method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is a sketchy part of the setup, if you happen to initialize your project without setting up the SHA-1 first and google sing in from authentication in Firebase, you will have a client_id (token id) inside your `google-servies.json` that is different from the one stored in Firebase.

To solve this, check first the token you have inside the file generated in your project.

### **google-services.json**

Make sure that these two ids
[image]

Are the same as the one in Firebase

[image]

If not, just copy the one from the firebase web page and paste it inside your `google-services.json` file, re-run the project and that should work